# скопировать файлы из одной папки в другую, если файл есть в третьей папке

Tags: powershell

Есть набор файлов в папке C:\prog.Api. Нужно скопировать из C:/bin в C:/alpha те файлы, которые есть в C:\prog.Api (совпадение имени и расширения).
Написал это

```
Get-childitem "C:\prog.Api" | Copy -filter {$_.Name} -Path C:\bin -Destination C:\alpha
```

но ругается на то, что входные данные конвейера не используются командой. Не знаю куда копать можно вообще такое провернуть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\prog.Api" | # получаем все файлы в prog.api
    Where-Object { Test-Path "C:\bin\$($_.Name)" } | # выбираем только те, которые есть в папке bin
    ForEach-Object { Copy-Item "C:\bin\$($_.Name)" "C:\alpha\" } # для каждого такого файла запускаем копирование из bin в alpha
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    param(
    $one = 'C:\tmp\one',
    $two = 'C:\tmp\two',
    $tree = 'C:\tmp\tree'
)

gci $two | ? {$_ -notin (compare -ReferenceObject (gci $one) -DifferenceObject (gci $two)).InputObject} | copy -Destination $tree
```